# Acceder a una variable JSP desde otra JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Tengo un jsp `menu.jsp`

```
        <li <%  if(pps_pag==1){ out.println("class='active'");} %> >
            <a href="usuarios.jsp" onclick="javascript:$('#cargando').modal();">
                <i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Gestión usuarios</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li <%  if(pps_pag==2){ out.println("class='active'");} %> >
            <a href="nuevaTabla.jsp" onclick="javascript:$('#cargando').modal();">
                <i class="fa  fa-plus"></i> <span>Nueva tabla</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

Y ese jsp que básicamente es un menú, lo incluyo en las diferentes páginas `jsp`, por ejemplo:

`usuarios.jps`

```
...
<jsp:include page="menu.jsp" />
<% int pps_pag = 1;%> <%-- Esto no funciona, es para que se entienda lo que quiero--%>
...
```

Ahora quiero poder asignar un valor desde `usuarios.jsp` a la variable `pps_pag`, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: A diferencia de los atributos que existen en `request` o `session` o `application`, los objetos que existen en `pageContext` no se comparten entre diferentes JSPs.

Comment: @PaulVargas entonces ¿puedes proponer una alternativa?

Comment: @nachfren sí, que tu atributo lo setees en `request` scope en lugar de setearlo en `pageContext`.

Comment: Vale ahora lo he entendido, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría funcionarte esto:
[jsp:param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150683/passing-parameters-to-another-jsp-file-using-jspinclude-tag)

O en su defecto, realizar una variable de tipo **session** y setear al valor antes de cargar dicha JSP, como lo comentaron anteriormente.

Saludos!!